Beginner Basict Python: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute on include
I'm trying to send messages to a Telegram group. To do this, I use:
main.py
....
import listings as list
....
from utils import *

utils.py
async def send_message_TEST():
    chat_id='some_chat_id'
    message_text = list.TEST
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message_text, parse_mode="HTML")

async def send_message_RULES():
    chat_id='some_chat_id'
    message_text = list.RULES
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message_text, parse_mode="HTML")

async def send_message_TABLE():
    chat_id='some_chat_id'
    message_text = list.TABLE
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message_text, parse_mode="HTML")

listings.py
TEST = '<b>some text for tests</b>'

RULES = '<b>Two lines text</b>\n\n' \
        '<b>Second line</b>\n\n' \

TABLE = '<b>one more</b>'

and got this error:
Dec 23 15:14:00 p6539.kvmvps python3.12[494]: ERROR:apscheduler.executors.default:Job "send_message_TEST (trigger: cron[hour='15', minute='14'], next run at: 2024-12-24 15:14:00)" raised an exception
Dec 23 15:14:00 p6539.kvmvps python3.12[494]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 23 15:14:00 p6539.kvmvps python3.12[494]:   File "/root/bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/apscheduler/executors/base.py", line 181, in run_coroutine_job
Dec 23 15:14:00 p6539.kvmvps python3.12[494]:     retval = await job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
Dec 23 15:14:00 p6539.kvmvps python3.12[494]:              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Dec 23 15:14:00 p6539.kvmvps python3.12[494]:   File "/root/bot/utils.py", line 3, in send_message_TEST
Dec 23 15:14:00 p6539.kvmvps python3.12[494]:     message_text = list.TEST
Dec 23 15:14:00 p6539.kvmvps python3.12[494]:                    ^^^^^^^^^
Dec 23 15:14:00 p6539.kvmvps python3.12[494]: AttributeError: type object 'list' has no attribute 'TEST'

Try (), [] - with no result

Naming a module after a built in type seems like a very bad idea. Can you give it any other name?

The quick and dirty fix seems to be to add the line: import listings as list near the top of utils.py

Importing listings in main.py does not make it available in utils.py.
